# Google Analytics configured with GTM showing two pageviews. But when I check GTM assistant it only shows one

Tags: google-analytics, next.js, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I have configured Google Analytics using GTM in my single-page application build in next.js. In order to check the pageviews I push a custom event to the data layer called "pageview" each time a user change to a new page.

In GTM I have created a trigger that looks for the "pageview" custom event and fires up the google-analytics tag.

Everything seems to be working properly but when I enter the debugview of google analytics and I change from one page to another 2 paweviews are recorded instead of one.

I have check GTM assistant and the tag is not firing twice, so I do not know where the problem might be.

This is messing my stats as I have twice more pageviews than in reality.

Here in the photos i upload you can see the tag. In the history and message no tags are getting fired

[image]

While this is what happens in google analytics (both page_views contain the exact same parameters (same page_refererr, page_location...):

[image]

Here is the implementation insine next.js. Basically I call the function GTMPageView() each time a route is change. GTMPageView() is the function that pushes "pageview" into the datalayer

[image]

I really appreciate any kind of help as I have been hours trying to solve the problem and I cant get to the end of it.

Comment: This could be related to the implementation in the app. Could you share the relevant code from the Next.js app?

Comment: Okay i just did

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, it is normal. When you stop the GTM preview mode it will only show one again

Comment: How did you stop the default page_view event since you already have a custom pageview event ?